# Align dynamic textviews one after another

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Is there any possible way that I can align dynamically created textviews like this ?.[image]

This is my response and I want to convert each of the skill and platform into textview in the design above and align one after the other.

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "skills": "HTML5, MYSQL,",
        "platforms": "Static Website, Dynamic Website, E-Commerce Website, Android Application, Web Portal"
    }
],
"status": 100
}
```

Comment: Try this library https://github.com/whilu/AndroidTagView

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Narayan C.R- Show your code. I mean what have you done for this. ?

Comment: I have already tried adding dynamic textview with the required background  in relative layout and linear layout. But it will not wrap as I require. The content will not start in a new line. Only possibility is to achieve using a relative layout, but fetching id and align to one below and aside of another seems impossible. also tried grid and table row.

Answer (score 2):

1) Convert comma seperated string to list by List items = Arrays.asList(str.split("\s*,\s*"));

2) try this https://github.com/Plumillon/ChipView ,

ChipView enables you to easily create Chip list with optional click listener on each Chip.

ChipView is highly customizable to the point you can control every Chip layout and background colors (normal and selected) individually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, try using `Recyclerview` with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` if you don't want to use any third party library.

Answer (score 0):

Why not, you can simply create a dynamic Relative layout in your activity

```
width = MATCH_PARENT
height = WRAP_CONTENT
```

layout params, and keep on appending as many textviews as you want inside it.

Look for how to create textviews dynamically and that must solve your doubt.

BEST PART : you don't need any external library for this, unless you want advance beautifications and features.